# Sizing Box User Control

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls, move

I am writing a control in vb.net that will allow a user to resize something. So far, resizing works, but I can't get moving to work properly, instead of moving where the mouse moves, it seems to flicker between two positions, but I can't figure out where these positions are coming from. It follows the mouse *sort of*. I know the explanation isn't very good so here is some code so you can see for your self: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VVfKpZFj).

Apologies for this bad quality (please point out the bad stuff so I can correct), but this is *really* giving me a nightmare and I couldn't figure out a clean way to write this.

If anyone has any answers as to why it wont move to the correct position, I would be very grateful!

Edit: To clear the code up *a little*, the moving takes place where the selected handle is "m". Which is this part:

```
If SelectedHandle.Contains("m") Then
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.None Then
        SelectedHandle = ""
    Else
        Me.Location = e.Location
    End If
End If
```

Changing it to this works, but it jumps to the middle of the control whereas I would like it to move relative to where the user clicked the mouse on the control

```
If SelectedHandle.Contains("m") Then
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.None Then
        SelectedHandle = ""
    Else
        Dim newloc = Me.Location
        newloc.Offset(e.X, e.Y)
        newloc.Offset(-0.5 * Width, -0.5 * Height)
        Me.Location = newloc
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like **y_difference** and **x_difference** are calculated using the **X** and **Y** coordinates which can be relative to the context where the move (or click) happens. Check the article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.y.aspx).

> For example, when the Control.MouseMove event is handled, the mouse coordinate values are relative to the coordinates of the control that raised the event

Always using **e.Location** should give the correct numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I needed to store the offset of the mouse on mouse down, not when it moved. A stupid mistake! The new code is [here](http://pastebin.com/7wZDCETT). It now works as expected, although the code is still very ad-hoc.